# How to find all the indexes of all the occurrences of a substring in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I am wondering if this is even possible without making any import method. But in a given string it is possible to make a list of all the indexes of all the occurrences.

For instance:

`s = 'AACATGAACAAG'`

for the occurrence AA the output should be:

`result = [0, 6, 9]`

which are al the positions...

Comment: How can 3 be a valid result? And do you want overlapping checks too? Can you please add the [tag:python] tag as well?

Comment: sorry it was an error